# What is the best way to store information across pages for a very short amount of time?

Tags: javascript, variables, cookies, local-storage

I am building customized thank-you pages that a user get redirected to after they successfully submitted a form. The tank-you page should take up some of the information that the user has submitted in the form on the previous page.

I am thinking about writing a short-lived (20 seconds or so) cookie which i can have read by the tank-you page, but it seems a little overkilling. What would be the best way to propagate that information to the thank-you page?

Comment: use sessions? What is your back-end language?

Comment: my backend is in nodeJS. can you hint me towards a good article about how to solve this using sessions?

Comment: I never used sessions with node.js (I barely used node.js in fact) Google might help you better than me.